# Android SoundPool only can play audio/Video from Raw or asset folder not from SDcard?

Tags: android, sd-card, soundpool

Hello all in one of my app  need to play sound using SoundPool... But it has method like

I need to change the speed of playing mp3 that is stored in sdcard

```
  sndPool.play(sound_id, leftVolume, rightVolume, 1, 0, rate);
```

the path

we can not give path of sdcard file?

I have read that there is method like

> sndpool.load(string path)

But this method does not support rate parameter

I need to change the speed of playing mp3

How to achive this?

Comment: use setRate(id, rate) method

Comment: what should i pass id? the file is loaded from sdcard?

Answer (score 0):

> we can not give path of sdcard file?

Not via that particular convenience method.

Also, bear in mind that [you do not have access to an "sdcard", in general, on Android 4.4+](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). Perhaps you really mean [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) when you say you are working with the "sdcard".

> I need to change the speed of playing mp3 How to achive this?

Call [`setRate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#setRate%28int,%20float%29), presumably. While the JavaDocs make it seem like the first parameter needs to be the `int` returned by `play()`, it should also work for the `int` returned by `load()`.

Comment: can you describe this? ?

Comment: @Pragna: `setRate()` is a method. Call it on the `SoundPool` instance. Pass in the return value from `load()` as the first parameter. Pass in your rate as the second parameter.